# Is there a python twitter search library that handle results the right way?

Tags: python, twitter

All the libraries I've tested search in twitter, let you specify the rpp (results per page) parameter but only gives you ONE page results.

It'd be cool a Python lib that provide a generator and each time gen.next() is called, a new search result is yielded. If the page is over, jump to the next page alone.

Comment: @Arrieta: if there's a Python Twitter Search Library that uses a generator to allow for results beyond the first page.

Comment: That is not directly possible with the REST API (because it replies JSON) - you could, of course, write a generator for the JSON response. However, maybe it is possible with the STREAMING API, but I am not aware of any Python solutions at the time. Still, I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve though.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was talking about: http://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/commit/e9aaaa7c39dad0306fec9e83cb377975f5c2d4d5

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, but I think the limit on what you can get is not a library limitation, but an API limitation (imposed by Twitter). You can read the methods available in their REST API [here](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search). Excerpt:

```
rpp
The number of tweets to return per page, up to a max of 100.
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=100
page
The page number (starting at 1) to return, up to a max of roughly 1500 results
(based on rpp * page).
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?page=10
```